# NSNumberFormatter class not rounding up to correct value

Tags: nsstring, rounding, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I am using NSNumberFormatter class to round a decimal number upto 2 digits and choosing the higher number while rounding up.

```
NSString *value = @"1054.705";
NSNumberFormatter *valueDouble = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
valueDouble.roundingMode = NSNumberFormatterRoundCeiling;
[valueDouble setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSNumber *myNumber = [valueDouble numberFromString:value];

Desired Output : 1054.71
Output Coming : 1054.705
```

So in this case round of 0.705 will always should be 0.71 what ever be the digits at the end.

Comment: where do you get the output from? Console or App (textfield, lable etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle such cases using this approach - check if second (or whatever) fraction digit is zero and ceil it than divide back

```
if ((NSInteger)(myNumber.doubleValue * 100) % 10 == 0) {
    myNumber = @(ceil(myNumber.doubleValue * 100) / 100);
}
```